# Infragistics XamDataGrid Expand Direction

Tags: infragistics, children, expand, xamdatagrid

is it possible to change the expand direction of the childrecords in an infragistics xamdatagrid? Currently the expand direction is down (childrecords expand down of the parentrecord). I need the change to expand the childrecords top of the parentrecord.

[orignial expand direction with childrecords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQAuN.png)

[new expand direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YSLt.png)

maybe with a style?
I use WPF and vb.net

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the [ChildRecordsDisplayOrder](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.datapresenter~infragistics.windows.datapresenter.fieldlayoutsettings~childrecordsdisplayorder) property.

Comment: Yes, it works. Can I use it only for one Record and not for the whole Grid? Currently I changed it on the FieldLayoutSettings, but I need on Record, which expand down, and another Record, which expand up in the same Grid

Comment: No i don't think there is such a setting per record - only for the fieldlayout.